# Horizontal collision issue with actionscript 3 flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

> In my platformcollision function, when the player is checking for collision on his left side everything is fine. My player doesnt go through, he can move the opposite way. However, when I put the warMage on the left and its checking if theres collision with the platform on his right side, the player immediately teleports next to the platform. I dont understand why as all I did was flip the arithmetic signs in that if statement from the other for the player to check its right side.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var Key:KeyObject = new KeyObject(stage);//Help the stage checks for   keypressed objects           //Initialized variable integers
var hsp:Number = 0;// horizontal speed
var vsp:Number = 0;// vertical speed
var grav:Number = 2;//Gravity
var fric:Number  = .5;//Friction
var floor:int = 800;//Bottom of the stage
//All Booleans
var lDown:Boolean = false;
var rDown:Boolean = false;
var jumped:Boolean = false;
var attacking:Boolean = false;


warMage.gotoAndStop("idleWarmage");//Initially starts at idle state
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, keyPressed);//Listens for buttons    pressed
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);// The physics applied  to character
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, platformCollision);

function keyPressed(e:Event):void
{
if(Key.isDown(Key.LEFT))//If we pressed the left arrow button
{

    lDown = true;//Condition to check if player is in running state
    if(lDown = true)//If we are running left
      {
         hsp -= 15;//Move left
         warMage.gotoAndStop("RunWarmage");//Play the running animation
         warMage.scaleX = -1;//Flip the image scale
      }
}else if(Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT))//If we pressed the right arrow button
{

    rDown = true;//Condition to check if player is in running state
    if(rDown = true)//If we are moving right
      {
        hsp += 15;//Move the position right
        warMage.gotoAndStop("RunWarmage");//Play the animation
        warMage.scaleX = 1//Face right
      }
}else if(Key.isDown(Key.SPACE))//If we press the spacebar
     {
         warMage.gotoAndStop("AttackWarmage");//Play teh attack animation
         warMage.x += 5; //Lunge right
         if(warMage.scaleX == -1)//If we are initially facing left
             {
                 warMage.x -= 10;//Lunge left
             }

     }else if(Key.isDown(Key.DOWN))
      {
        warMage.gotoAndStop("CrouchWarmage"); 

      }else if(Key.isDown(Key.UP) || jumped == true)//If we press the up arrow or we've jumped
      {

          warMage.y -= 60;//vertical speed goes up to 20
          jumped = true;//We know that player has jumped
          warMage.gotoAndStop("JumpWarmage");//Play teh jump animation

      }else if(jumped == false)//If we're not jumping
        {
            warMage.gotoAndStop("idleWarmage");//Return to idle position
        }
}


function gameloop(e:Event):void
{  
  warMage.y += grav;//Apply gravity to the player
  hsp *= fric;//Friction is applied to hsp to prevent infinite acceleration

  warMage.x += hsp;//The plater moves horizontal position
  if(warMage.x - warMage.width/2 < 0)//If the player goes past the left side
      {
          warMage.x = warMage.width/2;
      }
  if(warMage.x + warMage.width/2 > 1400)//If the player goes past right
      {
          warMage.x = 1400 - warMage.width/2;//Player cant go past
      } 
  if(warMage.y  < floor)//If we are above the floor
        {
         // warMage.y += grav;//Apply gravity to the player
          grav++;//Accelerate gravity in the process
          warMage.gotoAndStop("JumpWarmage");//Play the jump animation  

        } else //if(warMage.y - warMage.height/2 > floor)
          {

            jumped = false;//If we are on the floor then we're not jumping
            grav = 0;//Gravity can no longer be applied
            warMage.y = floor;//Player sits on top of the floor
          }
}

function platformCollision(e:Event):void
{
//If the player.x is less then the left side and the player can go into the box and if the warMage.y is equal to the  height
if(warMage.x - warMage.width/2 < platform.x + platform.width/2 + 2 && warMage.y - platform.y == platform.height/2) 
    {
        warMage.x = platform.x + platform.width/2 + warMage.width/2;
        //Player.x is equal to the left side of the platform

    }
if(warMage.x + warMage.width/2 > platform.x - platform.width/2 - 2 && warMage.y - platform.y == platform.height/2)
    {
        rDown = false;
        warMage.x = platform.x - platform.width/2 - warMage.width/2;
        //Player.x is equal to the left side of the platform

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need if/ else if in here instead of 2 ifs?

If this bit is true:

```
if(warMage.x - warMage.width/2 < platform.x + platform.width/2 + 2 && warMage.y - platform.y == platform.height/2)
```

and you set

```
warMage.x = platform.x + platform.width/2 + warMage.width/2;
```

Then the 2nd if would be true right away.
Now warMage.x is `platform.x + platform.width/2 + warMage.width/2;`
So checking 2nd if:

```
if(warMage.x + warMage.width/2 > platform.x - platform.width/2 - 2 && warMage.y - platform.y == platform.height/2)
```

So warMage.x (which is now `platform.x + platform.width/2 + warMage.width/2`) + warMage.width/2 is definitely greater than `platform.x - platform.width/2 - 2` and that's why you set

```
warMage.x = platform.x - platform.width/2 - warMage.width/2;
```

right after.

Looks like `platformCollision` needs rethinking.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. This 2d platformer code is seriously difficult .